# Button being made as an image to execute Javascript random generator

Tags: javascript, forms, function, button

Here is my code. I am trying to make a random game button, and I want to add [an image](http://login.edubox.co.uk/uploads/2/3/8/8/23885521/custom_themes/760822061530176408/files/Random%20Game%20Button.png?1386014254688) instead of the button, but when I change it, the random game element no longer works. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript">
<!--
function get_random()
{
var ranNum= Math.floor(Math.random()*89);
return ranNum;
}

function getaGame()
{
var whichGame=get_random();

var game=new Array(131)
game[0]= "";
game[1]= "http://www.edubox.co.uk/13-days-after.html";
up to...
game[130]= "http://www.edubox.co.uk/motherload.html";

location.href = game[whichGame];

}
//-->
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
<FORM name="form1">

<center>
<INPUT TYPE="image" src="http://login.edubox.co.uk/uploads/2/3/8/8/23885521/custom_themes/760822061530176408/files/Random%20Game%20Button.png?1386013897815" onClick="getaGame()" button style="font: bold 40px Impact; color: black">
</center>

</FORM>
```

It works fine. Sorry, my bad.

Comment: Need to explain "no longer works." What happens? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: Your code seems to work fine?

Comment: Well, it is supposed to randomly choose one of the links from a list. And work like a button. But I wanted to replace the default form button with an image, when I press the button, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know where your problem is, I did a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/DencS/) and, as you can see, it's working.

You were missing a ";" here though:

```
var game = new Array(131)
```

Edit: I also binded the event differently, it seems that the problem is somewhere there, if you change your button to this:

```
<INPUT TYPE="image" src="http://login.edubox.co.uk/uploads/2/3/8/8/23885521/custom_themes/760822061530176408/files/Random%20Game%20Button.png?1386013897815" button style="font: bold 40px Impact; color: black" id="btnGame">
```

And you bind the event like this:

```
document.getElementById('btnGame').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    alert(getaGame());
});
```

It should work, I don't know why your way doesn't work, but this can be a workaround.

Comment: It still doesn't work, as shown on my website http://www.edubox.co.uk/ :\ Sorry to bother you.